# Put a dataframe in chronological 'dd.mm.yyyy' order using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime-conversion

I have a csv-file with several columns, one contains the date in the format `dd.mm.yyyy`. Its entries (rows) aren't in chronological order. What I did to put them into order is transforming those values using `pd.to_datetime`, followed by `sort_values`. (Code below).

Desired output: `01.09.2019, 02.09.2019, 03.09.2019, ...., 30.03.2020`

However, I get: `01.01.2020, 01.02.2020, 01.09.2019, 01.11.2019, ..., 31.12.2019`

```
daten = pd.read_csv("gewichtstagebuch.csv", sep=";", decimal=",",
                usecols=("Datum","Gewicht (kg)"))
pd.to_datetime(daten['Datum'])
daten.sort_values(by="Datum", ascending= True)
```

I tried other ways to sort or convert my data set but [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6TdW.png) then Python assumes the months to be days and vise versa so that I still end up having the wrong result (e.g. forcing a format and strftime).

Comment: Did you try using pd.to_datetime(daten['Datum'], dayfirst=True)?

Comment: The to_datetime() function has a parameter (format) to which you can pass the format of the datetime you’re formatting so it knows how to parse.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime` returns a `datetime` hence it doesn't update your `daten` dataframe. The operation is not `in_place`.

Comment: [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has options `parse_dates`,  and you'll want `dayfirst = True` for dd.mm.yyyy format. You might need `infer_datetime_format = True` to handle the dot separator. In general you shouldn't need to retrospectively run `to_datetime()` on a column after reading the CSV - and it wastes tons of memory on temporarily storing date-strings.

Comment: @ Matthew Borish: Yes I did, it had no effect in the order of the dates.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of reading the data using pandas you can use "parse_dates" argument which will automatically convert the field into datetime.

```
daten = pd.read_csv("prob_data.csv", sep=",", decimal=",", parse_dates=[0],
                usecols=("Datum","Gewicht (kg)"))

daten.sort_values(by="Datum", ascending= True)
```

In the above code I have mentioned `parse_dates=[0]` considering the `first (0) column` is the date column. Once we load the data it will automatically convert the column to date column.

Now if you run the code to sort the dataframe it will sort the dataset accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Adrish, thanks for your help. I tried parse_dates as suggested in your comment but the result remains the same. First item of my list is 2019-01-09 followed by 2019-01-10 and so on. For me it seems it still assumes 01 to be January but actually the list starts with September.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.to_datetime` returns a `datetime` and hence doesn't update your `daten` dataframe. Therefore the sort doesn't work as expected.

Try to do the following:

```
daten = pd.read_csv("gewichtstagebuch.csv", sep=";", decimal=",",
                usecols=("Datum","Gewicht (kg)"))
daten = daten.assign(Datum=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.Datum)) # this returns a new dataframe
daten.sort_values(by="Datum", ascending= True)
```

Comment: Hi Afar, this code returns the following: 
2019-01-09 
2019-01-10 
2019-01-11 
2019-02-09
2019-02-10
... so unfortunately still no chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same or a similar problem - this solution suggested by smci solved the issue:

```
daten = pd.read_csv("gewichtstagebuch.csv", sep=";", decimal=",", parse_dates=[0],
                infer_datetime_format= True, dayfirst=True,
                usecols=("Datum","Gewicht (kg)"))
daten.sort_values(by="Datum", ascending= True)
```

So the combination of parse_dates, infer_datetime_format and dayfirst. Now I get the desired order:

2019-09-01
2019-09-02
2019-09-03
2019-09-04
...